# Temporary object destruction

Tags: c++, temporary

Why isn't destructor for temporary object called after evaluating a full-expression:

```
#include <iostream>


struct A 
{
    int a;
    A();
    ~A();
};

A::~A()
{
    std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; 
}

A::A()
{
    std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; 
} 



int main()
{
    A b = A(); //Constructing of temporary object and applies copy-initalization
    std::cout << "side effect" << std::endl;
    //Destructor calling.
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27c65dc012d7def2)**

Output:

```
A()
side effect
~A()
```

But 12.2/3 [class.temporary] says:

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that
>   has a non-trivial constructor (12.1, 12.8), it shall ensure that a
>   constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the
>   destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial
>   destructor (12.4). **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in**
>   **evaluating the full-expression** (1.9) that (lexically) contains the
>   point where they were created.

Comment: `-fno-elide-constructors`, see [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/022dd0982db9c024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your compiler and options the temporary is elided (optimized away), which is permitted.

Thus there is no temporary.

Thus there is no missing constructor and destructor call pair.

---

It's also well worth noting that the copy and move constructors are the only constructors where the compiler is allowed to *assume* that the constructor has no side effects, even when it knows better.

> ***C++11 §12.8/31***:
>   **”** When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. […]

Comment: Copy and move constructors, right?

Comment: @hvd: I think you're right, thanks. I was in C++03 mode. But I don't have time to check it. Can you please fix if you're sure?

Comment: Commenting is hard enough on a phone. It can wait till you have time to check :)

Comment: It's both (§12.8/31: "_When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. [...]_")